# Paste HTML code from XML to page like HTML and like String

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml, webforms

I have problem with parsing my HTML code from XML

Here some code for introducing

```
<item>
        <title>
          My HTML code
        </title>
        <description>
          <![CDATA[Here some example
          <ul style="list-style: disc;" type="disc">
            <li>Text1</li>
            <li>Text2</li>
          </ul>]]>
        </description>
      </item>
```

I'd like show this code in 2 ways, first like html list and second like string(make visible all tags e.g...)

I tried to grab this code in 2 ways and in booth result are same

```
string DescriptionCurent = item.Element("description").Value.ToString();
HtmlString html2 = new HtmlString(item.Element("description").Value.ToString());
```

And on the end I show this on page

```
<p><%= DescriptionCurent  %></p>
<p><%: html2 %></p>
```

On the end we have text before  in p tag, and list outside P tag showing like regular list.

I use asp.net 4.5 web forms

If you can't understand something pls ask and I will try to explain better

UPDATE:

I cant add images because i need 10 reputation so i put it on some free host

Here is image ho that look
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2eam7bb&s=8#.VQLYLY7F91A

And here it's in inspect element how look
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zv205h&s=8

so I just need to add everything in

tag no outside

Comment: What is the output you're receiving from your current code?

Comment: what type is `item` variable?

Comment: item iz XElement variable

Comment: @Nathan as I say result is "Here some example" in <p> tag and outside tag i see list

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `item` is an `XElement` from LINQ-to-XML. So, to get XML markup from an `XElement` object you simply call `ToString()` on *the object* (not on the object's `Value` property) :

```
HtmlString html2 = new HtmlString(item.Element("description").ToString());
```

Or a different way if you meant to get, specifically, the content of the CDATA element (excluding the `<CDATA>` tag itself) :

```
XCData cdata = (XCData)item.Element("description").FirstNode;
HtmlString html2 = new HtmlString(cdata.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes item is XElement. I tried booth cases but result is same.